# Angular material datepicker always open

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-material

I would like to use the angular material datepicker as a widget to control an instance of fullCalendar. Is there a way to force it to stay alway open and in a particular div? I know how to do it easily with bootstrap or jqueryUI but I would not want to add an extra dependency to my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can get that to work with some CSS, but the internal scroll position of the month scroller starts always at the top (1932).
`md-calendar` is the internal directive that renders the datepicker, so just use that.

```
<md-calendar class="fixed-calendar" ng-model="myDate"></md-calendar>
```

And set the CSS to fixed size, which is usually calculated by the datepicker.

```
.fixed-calendar {
  width: 340px;
  height: 340px;
  display: block;
}

.fixed-calendar .md-calendar-scroll-mask {
  width: 340px !important;
}

.fixed-calendar .md-virtual-repeat-scroller {
  width: 340px !important;
  height: 308px;
}
```

But you can probably write your own directive that requires the `mdCalendar` controller and set the scroll position there.

http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/EPQpGE

Comment: What if, let's say I want the width to be 280px? Just changing the 340 to 280 isn't doing the trick..

Comment: I don't think you can go below 340px.

Comment: Hi, I am using the same inside `md-dialog`. Is there any to switch the months or year using click event instead to scrolling?

Answer (score 12):

it's working on angular version 6.x

```
<mat-calendar [selected]="selectedDate" 
(selectedChange)="selectedChange($event)" 
(yearSelected)="yearSelected()" 
(monthSelected)="monthSelected()" 
(_userSelection)="userSelection()" 
(cdkAutofill)="cdkAutofill()">
</mat-calendar>
```

Emits when the currently selected date changes

```
readonly selectedChange: EventEmitter<D>;
```

Emits the year chosen in multiyear view.
This doesn't simply a change on the selected date

```
readonly yearSelected: EventEmitter<D>;
```

Emits the month chosen in year view.
This doesn't simply a change on the selected date

```
readonly monthSelected: EventEmitter<D>;
```

Emits when any date is selected

```
readonly _userSelection: EventEmitter<void>;
```

but still missing some needed events
like an event for the next and previous buttons

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiHen.png)

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4801)

[calendar.ts](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/datepicker/calendar.ts)

Comment: Is there a way to highlight a day when it's selected? If I click on a day I get the event but the style is not changing - it's just white ^^

Comment: @StefanFalk I think your problem is from the material theme styling.
 highlight day works properly without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @kuhnroyal his answer. If you want to go below 340px of width you can do the following:

```
.time-date {
  font-size: 12px !important;
}
.fixed-calendar {
  width: 280px;
  height: 285px;
  display: block;
}

.fixed-calendar .md-calendar-scroll-mask {
  width: 280px !important;
  height: 240px !important;
}

.fixed-calendar .md-virtual-repeat-scroller {
  width: 280px !important;
  height: 246px;
}

.fixed-calendar .md-calendar-date-selection-indicator {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
}
```

This for instance, sets the width to 280px. Just be sure that you set the selection indicator as well.

I wanted the height to be 240px as well, therefore I set the height of the scroll mask to 240px.