# Angular 6 and bootstrap 4: date picker

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I have a form which contain a date picker / calender, email, city name and hotel name, I want a user to select a date and enter other fields and submit the data.

This is what I have.

HTML:

```
 <form [formGroup]="angForm" class="form-element">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of Birth</label>
          <input id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" [(ngModel)]="dateOfBirth" type="text" bsDatepicker class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-element_email">
          <input type="email" class="form-control info" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" #email (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].invalid && (angForm.controls['email'].dirty || angForm.controls['email'].touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].errors.required">
            Email is required.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_city">
          <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" #cityName>
            <option selected *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city.name">{{city.name}}</option>

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_hotel">
          <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" #hotelName>
            <option selected *ngFor="let hotel of hotels" [ngValue]="hotel.name">{{hotel.name}}</option>

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" (click)="addReview(email.value, cityName.value , hotelName.value)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block form-element_btn"
            [disabled]="!validEmail">Book</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

This dispalys the following result: **wrong one**

[image]

Instead of that input with date picker  , I just want the full calender to be display on the left side ,

Here is what I want . **Good one**

[image]

I tried many solution online I could not be able to solve my problem,

What do I need to change in my code to get the result I want?  please  Am newbie though, thanks

Comment: It's not really displaying the wrong one. That's just how the datepicker works from bootstrap. What you are really looking for is a completely different component that you could use. Here is a very fancy calendar component https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink . But essentially you're looking for something like that. A separate component that can be used to select the date, not one built into an input box.

Comment: Hi, I saw it but i didnt like the way its designed, there is no other plugin or something similar to what I want apart from kitchen-sink?

Comment: Here is an example where someone did it with angularjs and material. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947571/angular-material-datepicker-always-open . The gist is to basically just always show the date picker. 

After inspecting the datepicker code for ngx it looks like bs-datepicker-container is the component name for the datepicker itself. So maybe can hack away at that and restyle it. Link to the src code for the ngx datepicker https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/tree/development/src/datepicker

Comment: solved with igx-calendar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually provide `placement` in the element which uses bdDatepicker directive.
Just set this `placement` property to `left` value.
Here is example in documentation.
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#placement